# If a common noun is capitalized in a title (headline-style), does it need to be capitalized in the body (or anywhere else that isn't a title)?

Tags: capitalization

I work in education, and we follow Chicago for most things. We also want to down style where we can. I was wondering if I could get some clarity on this situation.

For example, if an activity sheet for students is titled at the top of a document "Financial Wellness Activity Sheet," do I need to capitalize "activity sheet" in the body text of lessons or anywhere else if it follows Financial Wellness or if it stands alone?

I'm thinking that activity sheet becomes general, so a sentence would use it like, "Have students work on the Financial Wellness activity sheet." Or, "reference the Financial Wellness activity sheet." Or in a list of materials, "Financial Wellness activity sheet"

Am I wrong? Most that I work with see this as fine, but another person involved is suggested these takes capitals everywhere.

Similarly, things like "Part A, Part B, etc." are subheadings in these sheets are capitalized, but when referenced in lessons, I'd suggest them as "part A..."

Comment: It's the capitalization of the common nouns in the title that's the exception, not the other way around. It's no different than capitalizing any word at the start of a sentence. Just because you do it there, you don't think of doing everywhere … In the running text, you don't capitalize common nouns (unless they are at the start of a sentence).

Comment: I appreciate the response! I've been in my head about it. So there wouldn't be an issue with my suggestions in quotes? And saying things like, "take a look at part A" vs. "take a look at Part A" (in running text)

Comment: I agree with @Jason Bassford. But I'd also say that you need not feel that you must capitalize "Financial" and "Wellness" either in the text. You do treat them a bit in the title as a proper noun (the combination of the two), but that doesn't have to transfer to their usage in the body of the text.

Comment: @user382621 In the running text, you would only capitalize Financial Wellness if it actually *is* a proper noun. If that's the actual name of the activity sheet, then it might be fine. But consider that you could have two financial wellness sheets, one actually named *Financial Wellness* and the other named (for example) *Revenue Results*. Then you might say something like the following: *Refer to the financial wellness sheet Financial Wellness and the financial wellness sheet Revenue Results.* If it's lowercase or uppercase, it's referring to something specifically different, grammatically.

Comment: Mm, I follow Chicago, and I would cap it all: *Financial Wellness Activity Sheet.* Instructions should be drop-dead simple -- make what you're referencing match. (But, really, -- and I know this is not under your control -- I would not name a sheet Sheet. That much should be obvious to the user.)

Comment: Financial Wellness Activity Sheet should have each word starting in upper case when used as the heading or title, but when used in the text matter, it need not be so.  As an alternative on first time use in the text, use it as an acrynym like Financial Wellness Activity Sheet (FWAS), which can be used in the succeeding parts.

Comment: Even used in parts like financial wellness, or activity sheet, it need not necessarily be in upper case in running text mtter because it is composed of common nouns, except when used as sub-head/ sub-title.